# Is there any standard to put dimension files for different wear devices in android?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am developing a wear app. Inside Android-23 wear SDK  system images folder, I can see different dimensions of wear devices(like 480x480,360x325), round,round-chin,square etc

I want to give for elements like icons inside my app , those device specific dimensions using different dimesions.xml files.

is there any standard way to achieve this?.Do suggest.